# Authenticating between a Google Cloud Scheduler job and Google App Engine endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a Google Cloud Scheduler set to hit a Google App Engine endpoint `myservice.appspot.com/endpoint` once a day. How can I authenticate the identity of my Google Cloud Scheduler in my Google App Engine endpoint? I am using Python and Flask.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you looking at how to validate a Google Identity Token that Cloud Scheduler includes in the Authorization header, or are you trying to configure authorization in App Engine?

Comment: @JohnHanley It wouldn't be a user OAuth token. I'm trying to configure authorization in App Engine. My initial thinking was passing a token from scheduler to App Engine, but that would mean I would have to hardcode a token into the scheduler request body

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. EDIT your question to be more specific. You can either use a secret key (of your own design) or have Cloud Scheduler add the Identity Token to the HTTP authorization header.